# We're dropping to ~1 question per day

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, recent-activity

Checking our [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94441/retrocomputing), question activity has nearly dropped to a standstill, just over 1 question a day.  How can we encourage users to continue to ask more high quality questions and encourage positive activity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good question.

It is true that question rate is an important criterion for graduation but there are 13 sites with a lower question rate than us.  That includes some that have been in beta for four and a half years.  I'm not dispirited.

For one thing, [spread the word](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/) that we are here.  We need a bit more visibility.  I've seen questions get closed elsewhere as off-topic but would have been good here.  If you see any, add a comment to them.  Just that bit of advertising is something.

There has been some work in the background about starting a blog (Kudos to @wizzwizz4 for effort).  That may help.

Historically, I've seen site activity generally pickup during Winterbash.  Thanks to the cross-site publicity that produces, I would expect some fresh users to come this way then.  Although of course that would be a few months off yet.

I've said before that we are building it, they will come.  That still holds true.

Comment: This pretty much sums up my POV on it. It was always going to be a slow grower with the number of dedicated forums around, but I do think that over time it'll become a more and more valuable resource. I've already seen a couple of questions from here cross promoted, I'm sure we'll get a few that would be of historical interest to large numbers of people that'll drive adoption.

Comment: Also, everything slows down during the summer for the users from the northern hemisphere.